# start menu button in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu

So I got Windows 8.1 and I got *A* Start menu button back ("Yes Jim, it's a Start menu - but not as we know it!").

Can it be customised to look like the classic Start Menu (for the Desktop) or do I have to go and get a third party app?

TIA,
Paolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make it look like the classic Windows start button through the default settings. But you can use 3rd party programs like Classic Shell or Stardock Start 8.

Here is a list of alternatives you can use to emulate the Start menu:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Start_Menu_replacements_for_Windows_8